# Use wxpython to display txt files

Tags: wxpython

I have completed an algorithm in python and save a result in each .txt file.  I plan to display multiple .txt files in GUI when we need it? But i don't know how to display it? Is there any person can help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll get better responses if you show us your attempts at using the wx library, rather than just asking for us to code an app for you.

Answer (score 0):

A basic widget you can use is `wx.TextCtrl`.  There are other options, but this is a good starting point.

Usually when I start looking for widgets, I start with the [wxPython demo](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php), which has many good examples.  Here's a screenshot with a few wx.TextCtrl options.

[image]

The general procedure you want to follow is: 1) read through a tutorial to get the app running with a wx.Frame showing, and put a widget in this frame; 2) put in a wx.TextCtrl widget; 3) read in the text file and put this data into the widget at creation, or with, eg, [`SetValue`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/TextEntry.html#TextEntry.SetValue) after the widget is created.